# Apply [Authorize] attribute implicitly to all Web API controllers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My application is setup where all requests except login must be 'authorized' using the authorization attribute in Web API.  E.g.

```
 [Authorize]
 [HttpGet, Route("api/account/profile")]
 public ApplicationUser Profile()
 {
       return userModel;
 }
```

and only the login needs to not authorize since thats where you get the token ;)

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost, Route("api/account/login")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
   ....
}
```

instead of having to add the `[Authorize]` attribute to ALL my routes, is there a way to set it globally?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You have two options

1. Controller level by decorating your controller with authorize attribute.

   ```
   [Authorize]
   [RoutePrefix("api/account")]
   public class AccountController : ApiController
   {
   ```
2. You can also set it global level to all routes, in  `Register` method of WebApiConfig.cs file

   ```
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
   ```

Comment: I'd also recommend to put this inside a `#if !DEBUG #endif` block, so this could ease debugging without the need for authorization.

Comment: I did this, but now I get ALWAYS 401, sure I'm missing something... what else I need to add?

Comment: Side-note: recent version of .net core api, need to add `Policy` for `AuthorizeAttribute` as Matt Frear answered below.

Answer (score 23):

You can set the `AuthorizeAttribute` to the `WebApiConfig` file like below:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
  );
  config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Now all methods from your Web Api controllers will need authorization. If you want to remove this authorization requirement for a method, you need to add the attribute `[AllowAnonymous]` like in the Login action method.

Answer (score 14):

Since ASP.NET Core 3.0 there is a new way to do this without filters by using the Endpoint Routing middleware, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#authorization

You need to add the following if it's not already there:

```
services.UseAuthentication(); // with authentication scheme
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization(); // this is enough, because DefaultPolicy is to require authentication
```

and to the Endpoint middleware:

```
endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
```

An example with JWT authentication scheme:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
         };

    });
}
   

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
    });
}
```

You can still allow anonymous access with `[AllowAnonymous]` on a controller or action (eg. for user login).

Answer (score 6):

In ASP.NET Core Web API, it's like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(o =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();

        o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
}
```

Source: https://joonasw.net/view/apply-authz-by-default

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add something to other answers that if you use

```
 filters.Add(container.Resolve<AuthorizeAttribute>());
```

then you can also inject all dependencies into your attribute if there is a need

Answer (score 0):

I use another approach - because all my ApiController classes are derived from my own custom class ControllerBase, I just have set my custom attribute [RequireAuthorization] to this base class. So this gets inherited to all derived controller classes.