# Apply my custom "Authorize" attribute to all routes in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, authorize

How to add custom authorize attribute to all routes in ASP.NET Core?

I have my own custom authorize attribute and want to add it to all routes of my application. If a request comes to any route, first check my custom attribute, then resume request. I can do it by applying it manually on every controller or action, but i want do it for all controllers and actions automatically.

It's like

```
app.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
```

If want to use my custom attribute, how to apply it to all routes?

Comment: `config.Filters.Add(new YourAttribute());` in your app registration - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916870/apply-authorize-attribute-implicitly-to-all-web-api-controllers